# IF STATEMENT GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I have this conditional statement:

```
=IF(AD6=0,0,AG6)
```

what I am trying to do is check if AD6 is equal to 0, then set AG6 = 0 as well. however, that doesn't seem to be working with this formula. Nothing changes.

I also tried:

```
=IF(AD6=0,AG6=0)
=IF(AD6=0,0,AG6=0)
```

below is an image on what I currently have in the spreadsheet:
[image]

basically, AD6 is the left column, and then column on the far right is AG6. basically, as you can see, if AD6 is equal to 0, I want to set AG6 = 0 too.

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance temporarily, I created a new column I am putting it into.

Comment: AG6 I have the number 2 in right now.

Answer (score 1):

check your formatting. try:

```
=IF(AD6="0"; 0; AG6)
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work either. same result

Comment: @devdude19289 can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, you can't change the value of another cell with a formula. For example, you wouldn't be able to put a formula in AI6 that changes the value of AG6. If you have values inserted in AD6 and AG6 you can return a value in another column that reflects this condition. For example: `=IF(AD6=0,0,AG6)` - then, you would refer to that cell for your further calculations and not AG6